# Static Memory allocation in C

Tags: c, static-memory-allocation

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int foo;            /* a staticly allocated variable */

 int recur(int i) {      /* a recursive function */
     int j = i;            /* a stack allocated variable within a recursive function */
     printf("recur call (i)%d: stack@ %lx\n", i, (long unsigned int) &j); /* fix this so it print
 s the address of j */
     if (i > 0) {
         return recur(i-1);
     }
     return 0;
 }

 int stuff = 7;          /* a statically allocarted, pre-initialized variable */

 int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
     int i;            /* a stack allocated variable */
     char *buf1 = malloc(100); /* dynamically allocate some stuff */
     char *buf2 = malloc(100); /* and some more stuff */
     char *buf3 = malloc(100); /* and some more stuff */
     printf("_main  @ %lx\n", (long unsigned int) &main); /* fix to print address of main */
     printf("_recur @ %lx\n", (long unsigned int) &recur); /* fix to print address of recur */
     printf("main call (i):stack@ %lx\n", (long unsigned int) &i); /* fix to get address of the s
 tack variable */
     printf("_static foo: %lx\n", (long unsigned int) &foo); /* fix to get address of the static v
 ariable */
     printf("_static stuff: %lx\n", (long unsigned int) &stuff); /* fix to get address of a stati
 c variable */
     printf("Heap: malloc 1: %lx\n", (long unsigned int) buf1);
     printf("Heap: malloc 2: %lx\n", (long unsigned int) buf2);
     printf("Heap: malloc 3: %lx\n", (long unsigned int) buf3);
     recur(3);
     return 0;
 }
```

The output of this program comes out to be:

```
_main  @ 4005c2
_recur @ 40057d
main call (i):stack@ 7fff26397694
_static foo: 601050
_static stuff: 601048
Heap: malloc 1: 1862010
Heap: malloc 2: 1862080
Heap: malloc 3: 18620f0
recur call (i)3: stack@ 7fff2639766c
recur call (i)2: stack@ 7fff2639763c
recur call (i)1: stack@ 7fff2639760c
recur call (i)0: stack@ 7fff263975dc
```

Can anyone please explain followings?

- Why addresses are of different bytes eg. main, recur & static_varibale    addresses being 6*4=24 byte, heap being 7*4=28 bytes, stack being 12*4=48 byte address.
- Though I am allocating 100 bytes per malloc the difference between malloc 1 and malloc 2 addresses is 0x70 = 112 bytes
- Why there is a difference of 0x601050 - 0x601048 = 8 between the address of foo and stuff though both of them are int and int takes just 4 bytes?

Comment: alignment, maybe????

Comment: Side note: With function names, as with statically allocated arrays, there is no need to use `&` in order to obtain the address (e.g. `main` and `&main` are necessarily identical values).

Comment: Also, the stack frame for "recur" happens to be of 0x30=48 bytes. Is this value is fixed or function dependent? If its function dependent then the recur function only has two int variables declared 'i' and 'j' that makes 2*4= 8 bytes only, then why 48?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Every part of a program (code, data, stack ...) lives in different sections. These sections are mapped to memory regions by the OS, so the answer is that the difference you see is OS dependent. In your case, the stack happens to be mapped on a higher region, but all the addresses are still 64-bit (the address space can be less though, like 48-bit).
- `malloc()` is guaranteed to return an aligned pointer. In 64-bit environment, it usually is on a 16 bytes boundary, thus the 100 bytes you allocate will be 'rounded' to 112 (7*16) for the next allocation. Also, `malloc()` need to keep track of allocation with additional data, so the used space will always be higher than the malloc'ed amount.
- A major difference between `stuff` and `foo` is that one is initialized and the other one is not, thus `stuff` will be placed in the `.data` section, and `foo` will be placed in the `.bss` section (zero initialized section). This means that the two variable are unlikely to be next to each other. In your case they are near because there is nothing else.

Comment: Also, the stack frame for "recur" happens to be of 0x30=48 bytes. Is this value is fixed or function dependent? If its function dependent then the recur function only has two int variables declared 'i' and 'j' that makes 2*4= 8 bytes only, then why 48?

Comment: @UtkarshGupta The stack used by a function depends on many things. You can have local variables stored on the stack, CPU registers spilled (saved) on the stack, but also stack space reserved for functions calls. Also, x64 call convention require to align the stack on a 16 bytes alignement for function calls. And there is the return address pointer pushed on the stack, for an unavoidable 8 bonus bytes.

Comment: What is the difference between the terms segment and section?

Comment: @UtkarshGupta Usually, segment is referring to memory segmentation, so it's more related to memory. You could say the stack and the code are different in segments. Note that memory segmentation is not used anymore in 64-bit, so it's a somewhat obsolete term. Sections are just a way to separate the different parts of the program. You have sections like `.text` (code), `.data` (global vars), `.bss` (global zero'ed), `.rodata` (constants, like string literals). You can even define your own sections. There isn't really a stack or heap section, because these are run-time only.

Comment: @UtkarshGupta segments refer to "memory segmentation", a trick implemented by early x86 processors to be able to address a a 1MB memory space with 16bit addresses. In short, a logical memory address is divided into two 16bit addresses: The first refers to a segment of memory (Say 0x0 to 0x0000FFFF), the second is an offset on that segment start (Say 0x000F). So an access like segment=0x1000, offset=0x000F results in the linear address 0x1000000F. Since modern processors all work with 32/64bit addresses and no longer have this problem, kernels always use segment 0 and 32/64bit offsetting.

Comment: @Manu343726 Thanks for the knowledge :)

Answer (score 3):

First let be clear that addresses are virtual memory addresses of your process memory space. That said, the layout of a process memory space is more or less like this for a 32bit environment:

```
  0 +----------------------------------------+
    |             .text (code)               |
    +----------------------------------------+
    |  .data (initialized static variables)  |
    +----------------------------------------+
    | .bss (uninitialized static variables)  |
    +----------------------------------------+ <- Heap start, grows upwards
    |                  heap                  |
    +----------------------------------------+
    |                  stack                 |
3GB +----------------------------------------+ <- Stack start, grows downwards 
    |               kernel code              |
4GB +----------------------------------------+
```

- Static variables addresses are not of shorter sizes, all addresses are 32bit addresses, it's only `printf()` truncating leading zeroes (Look at the diagram above, static variables have low addresses).
- `malloc()` usually places bookeeping data in addition to the allocated buffer itself. This is implementation dependent though.
- "`int` takes just 4 bytes", that depends on your system. Also the compiler could have added padding for stack frame alignment.